# Button flies off to the right in IE7, have been trying to fix this for ages

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been trying to fix this bug for ages and have finally turned to StackOverflow for help.
In IE7 on https://easygap.co.uk/4/getaquote/ the "Yes" button disappears and flies across the page to the very right (usually forces scroll too).

Any idea why it would do this and how I could fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the css `text-indent: 999px;` is one thats causing it.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it and used a blank value instead. Working great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's what I was about to add to my answer.
Oh .. and if my answer solved your purpose, you can accept it as a solution